# Subdomain on localhost with Nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to catch project1.localhost, here is the conf i tried but it doesn't catch anything.

```
server {
       listen 80;

       server_name project.localhost;

       location / {
                proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add line
127.0.0.1 project.localhost
to your hosts file (/etc/hosts in *nix).